# Unable to remove x-values from android from Android MpandroidChart library graph

Tags: android, real-time, linechart, axis-labels, mpandroidchart

I have implemented Mp android chart real-time line graph on my android application. I have set of records(both x and y values) saved. I want to navigate through each records using next button and want to corresponding graph.

My problem is when the next graph is loading everything working fine but I am unable to remove x-values. Hence for the next graph previous x-values are showing.
Can anyone help me???

```
  private void addEntryNew(String timevalue, String value){
    LineData data = mChart.getData();
    if (data != null) {
        set = data.getDataSetByIndex(0);

        if (set == null) {
            set = createSet();
            data.addDataSet(set);
        }
        data.addXValue(timevalue);
        data.addEntry(new Entry(Float.parseFloat(value), set.getEntryCount()), 0);

        mChart.notifyDataSetChanged();
        mChart.setVisibleXRange(12);
        mChart.moveViewToX(data.getXValCount() - 7);
    }
    /** Code for ToggleFilled */
     ArrayList<LineDataSet> sets = (ArrayList<LineDataSet>) mChart.getData()
             .getDataSets();

     for (LineDataSet set : sets) {
             set.setDrawFilled(true);
     }
     mChart.invalidate();
     xpos_list.add(data.getXValCount()-1);
}


    private void clearGraphMethod() {
    try {           
        mChart.clearValues();
        for(int i=0; i<xpos_list.size(); i++){
            data.removeXValue(xpos_list.get(i));
        }
        xpos_list.clear();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

}
```

Comment: I have edited my post. Please check once again. @PhilippJahoda

Comment: I am facing the same problem. Did you try mChart.setData(data) with no values?

Comment: I tried once but didn't worked. May be i was wrong. Can you tell me where to write this code? Have you solved your problem? @NicolasJafelle

Comment: Sorry, I am still working on this. Cannot find the proper solution.

Comment: Yes. Please share the solution with me too if you find one. I will do the same... @NicolasJafelle

Comment: Have you found the solution yet? @NicolasJafelle

Comment: @RanjitPaul Did you check version 2.1.0 ?? I fixed it with clear and then clearAllJobs()

Comment: I have implemented the graph. Which is working fine now. But i have another issue. My X-value differences are not same. Its in this way {0,3,6,9,12,15,18,21,24,26,28,32,48,64,80,96,97,98,99,100} and Y-values are dynamic. The differences between each vertical grid lines are same. I want it to be dynamic as per differences of X-values. Can you help me on this??? @PhilippJahoda

Comment: I have implemented the graph. Which is working fine now. But i have another issue. My X-value differences are not same. Its in this way {0,3,6,9,12,15,18,21,24,26,28,32,48,64,80,96,97,98,99,100} and Y-values are dynamic. The differences between each vertical grid lines are same. I want it to be dynamic as per differences of X-values. Can you help me on this??? @NicolasJafelle

Answer (score 1):

I had similiar problem, when I've tryied to restart graph.

So you declarate your xVals like this. Set the xVals arraylist as your local variable inside activity or fragment.

```
ArrayList<String> xVals = new ArrayList<String>();
 mLineData = new LineData(xVals,dataSets);
```

and than somewhere use clear() to start indexing you Xvalues from scratch

```
xVals.clear();
```

I hope it is answer for ur question.

Comment: I have implemented the graph. Which is working fine now. But i have another issue. My X-value differences are not same. Its in this way {0,3,6,9,12,15,18,21,24,26,28,32,48,64,80,96,97,98,99,100} and Y-values are dynamic. The differences between each vertical grid lines are same. I want it to be dynamic as per differences of X-values. Can you help me on this??? @murt

Comment: I don't understand you. You have fixed range of X-axis and you want your chart should grow vetricaly? Can you draw it?

Comment: Please see below post of mine.@murt

Comment: Here you have [my Fragment](https://github.com/GitHubMurt/GestureRecognition/blob/master/GyroscopeRealTimeData), inside it I use the MPChart.
The real-time data given on the chart comes from Gyroscope.
Look at **line 304** ,where I add new entry. When the number of samples reach the maximum **xRange** then Chart is moving forward, so the prevoius samples are no more visible (they still exist but the chart doesn't display them)

Answer (score 1):

```
private void addEntryNew(String timevalue, String value){
LineData data = mChart.getData();
if (data != null) {
    set = data.getDataSetByIndex(0);

    if (set == null) {
        set = createSet();
        data.addDataSet(set);
    }
    data.addXValue(timevalue);
    data.addEntry(new Entry(Float.parseFloat(value), set.getEntryCount()), 0);

    mChart.notifyDataSetChanged();
    mChart.setVisibleXRange(12);
    mChart.moveViewToX(data.getXValCount() - 7);
}
/** Code for ToggleFilled */
 ArrayList<LineDataSet> sets = (ArrayList<LineDataSet>) mChart.getData()
         .getDataSets();

 for (LineDataSet set : sets) {
         set.setDrawFilled(true);
 }
 mChart.invalidate();
 xpos_list.add(data.getXValCount()-1);
```

}

where should i properly used these @murt

ArrayList xVals = new ArrayList();

mLineData = new LineData(xVals,dataSets);